# Add a button to ribbon in SharePoint 2013 without using Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ribbon

Can any one let me know how can I add a button to the ribbon of a SharePoint 2013 list without using visual studio code? Whenever I click on the button it will go to a different URL.

Comment: You can use SPD for this. Go to the specific list and add a custom action.

Answer (score 7):

SharePoint Designer 2013 can be used to create a ribbon button for SharePoint list or library.  When clicked, the button will perform a custom action.

Step 1:
In SharePoint Designer 2013, open the site containing the library or list where the custom action button on the ribbon will be deployed.

Step 2:
Open the library or list from the left navigation panel.

Step 3:
Create the custom action by clicking on “Custom Action” button from ribbon and select “View Ribbon.”

Step 4: Give the custom action a name and description.

Step 5: Select Navigate to URL and enter the URL for the action. This will redirect the user to the specified URL when the ribbon button is clicked. Then select the URL of the image to display on the ribbon button and click OK button.

Step 6: 
Open the site & then your list in your browser for which custom action button was created.

Step 7: Click on the “Files” tab in the ribbon. Locate the new custom action button.