# Pulling Record from Custom List for purpose of Update

Tags: custom-list

I have a Custom List for sign out of books.

The librarian scans the book and enters the borrower information using a custom form. The book is added to the custom list via a record.

Is it possible to create a form that when the book is returned, the librarian scans the book and pulls up the sign out information. The end goal would be to allow the librarian to essentially check the book in.

Thanks

Comment: Which SharePoint version are Your using? On-premises or online?

Comment: Hi sorry. I forgot to add that. I'm using Sharepoint 2013 OP with SPD2013

Answer (score 1):

Since librarian already is using custom forms, then create a new one as You created existing forms using SharePoint Designer - Microsoft has [an artice](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-custom-list-form-using-sharepoint-designer-917d8fdb-ee00-4441-adb3-a94612d1d105) how to do it.

When the new custom form is ready, You have several options on how to provide the link to the librarians:

1) create ribbon button - our member Zakir HC has [provided answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114501/add-a-button-to-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2013-without-using-visual-studio) how to do it and Microsoft blog has [an article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/09/27/how-to-create-a-quick-step-and-custom-action-to-start-sharepoint-2013-workflow/) too.

2) create a new menu item in "list item drop down menu" - Nik Patel has a [blog post](https://nikpatel.net/2010/08/03/create-custom-list-item-menu-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/) how to do it.

3) editing existing forms and inserting link to the previously created form.